# Why is -1 returned if the character is not found in a string?

Tags: python

This returns `-1` Why is that?

```py
a = "apples"

print(a.find("g"))
```

This can be generated if you try to find a character that is nonexistent to the string.

Comment: Well, what would you *expect* it to return if the character isn't found?  (It can't be 0, as that's a valid index - `a.find("a")` would return that.)

Comment: @Nick: Unfortunately, in Python, `-1` is the index of the last character in a string (any sequence really). This is useful in general, but not in the case of `.find`.

Comment: @jasonharper: `-1` is a valid index too. In hindsight, returning `None` would probably have made more sense, but this decision is decades old, and basically impossible to reverse at this point.

Answer (score 2):

That's what it's documented to do. If you don't like it, you can always use `.index`, which behaves identically when the value is found, and raises an exception when it isn't found, removing the need to explicitly check the return value.